# Google Workspaces "Change Recipient" vs "Add More Recipients" - differing behaviours

Tags: gmail, google-workspace

When setting up a pattern-redirect in Google Workspaces > Gmail> Default Routing, I am getting bounces when using 'Change Envelope Recipient' > 'Replace Recipient'.

If I use the same address in 'Add More Recipients', then the BCC is delivered correctly.  If I use them both at the same time (replace & BCC) then I both receive a bounce at the sending address with 'address not found', and also the additional delivery at the target address.

I would prefer to 'Change Envelope Recipient' rather than 'Add more recipients' because I would like to set up some pattern redirects & then have a catch-all for anything that didn't match a pattern.  Eg

```
*.test@mydomain.com > test@mydomain.com
*.prod@mydomain.com > prod@mydomain.com
*@mydomain.com > catchall@mydomain.com
```

I assume (not tested) that if I have a rule that replaces the envelope that runs before my catch-all, the catch-all will not catch an email that has been redirected to an account.

I could of course just build a rule for the catch-all that ignores anything with the other rules matched, but ideally I would prefer not to do that.

Answer (score 1):

The problem turned out to be pretty simple: the greedy match-lots `+` symbol isn't allowed. (Noticed this nugget at the bottom of https://support.google.com/a/answer/1371417)

Somehow, that resulted in the pattern matching on "Add More Recipients", but bouncing on "Change Envelope Recipient"

The question is moot though because even though the rules execute in order, redirecting to a valid mailbox is not sufficient to keep the email out of the final "Catch-All" routing rule.  Unfortunately, as negative look-aheads dont exist in RE2, it seems what I'm trying to achieve isn't possible (would love to be told otherwise)